# Is this correct 你一個人到這裡嗎

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the context of asking a chinese person who is living in say, spain, for not too long a period, is the above sentence correct if I want to ask “did you come here all by yourself?/are you here all by yourself?”? Another possibility I thought of was 你到這裡一個人嗎

Comment: 你一個人到這裡嗎 is correct, but it is better to use '来' instead of  '到 ' for 'come' because 到 mostly mean 'arrive'. of course '来到' in '你一個人来到這裡嗎' would mean  'came and arrived'

Comment: In what context would you use 來到 instead of 到 ？

Comment: 1. 你來美国 (you come to the USA) 2.你到美国 (you arrive at the USA ) 3. 你來到美国 ( you come and arrive at the USA) . 來 and 到 describe a single action; 來到 is an action with a result complement.  All three are valid and common sentences just 來到 being a more detailed description of the action. If it is just 到, it could be 被運到, 被送到 or 被押到

Answer (score 1, accepted):

你一個人到這裡嗎 is mostly correct. The complete version is 你是一个人到这里来的吗

A native way of saying so is 你是自己来这里的吗？A more northern version of it is 你是自个ge3（儿）来这（儿）的吗？

你到這裡一個人嗎 Is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

你一个人到这里来吗？
你一个人来这里的吗？
你自己一个人来西班牙？
你一个人来西班牙吗？